# UFD free modules of rank 1

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a [UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain), $M$ a free module over $A$, and $N$ a finitely generated rank 1 submodule. I have a relatively quick proof (about half a page) that if $(A\smallsetminus\{0\})^{-1}N \cap M = N$, then $N$ is also free. This is done by induction, reducing the number of generators to 1.

However, I feel like my proof is superficial, and that there should be a "deeper" proof in some sense. So my question is:

Is there some deep reason that the above statement should be obvious?

Comment: I am not sure I have interpreted faithfully the condition $A^{-1}N \cap M = N$. Could you make clear what $A^{-1}N$ means?

Comment: @LucGuyot Let $K$ denote the field of fractions of $A$. $A^{-1}N = K \otimes_A N \subseteq K \otimes_A M$; $M$ is a shorthand for the module $A \otimes_A M$.

Comment: Thanks, so $A^{-1}N$ is just $S^{-1}N$ with $S = A \setminus \{0\}$, that is the localisation with respect to the multiplicative subset $S$. This is how I interpreted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be an integral domain and let $N \subseteq M$ be two modules over $A$. The condition $S^{-1}N \cap M = N$ for $S = A \setminus \{0\}$ is equivalent to $N \cap aM = aN$ for every $a \in A$, provided  that $M$ is torsion-free. Hence, in this case, $N$ is a pure sub-module of $M$ in a weak sense.

We can prove the following claim without using induction on the number of generators of the sub-module $N$.

> > **Claim.** Let $A$ be a a  [GCD domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain), let $M$ be a free module over $A$ and let $N$ be a finitely generated sub-module of $M$ of rank $1$. If 
> >     $N \cap aM = aN$ for every $a \in A$ then $N \simeq A$.

The following lemma will help us reduce to the case $M = A$.

> > **Lemma 1.** Let $A$ be a  [GCD domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain), and let $M$ be a free module over $A$ of finite rank $n > 0$. Let $x$ be a non-zero element in $M \otimes_A K \simeq K^n$ where $K$ denotes the field of fractions of $A$. Then $M \cap Ax \simeq A$.
> >
> > *Proof.* Write $x = (\frac{a_1}{b_1},\dots, \frac{a_n}{b_n})$, with $\text{gcd}(a_i, b_i) = 1$ for every $i$. For $a  \in A$, we have $ax \in A^n$ if and only if $a \in \bigcap_i Ab_i$. Since $A$ is a GCD domain, the latter intersection is a principal ideal.

Now we can proceed to the proof of the claim.

> > *Proof of the Claim.*  As $N$ is finitely generated, we can assume without loss of generality, that $M$ has finite rank $n > 0$. We identify then $M$ and $N$ with their images in $K^n = M \otimes_A K$ where $K$ is the field of fractions of $A$. Since the rank of $N$ is $1$, there is $x \in K^n$ such that $N \subseteq Kx$. As $N$ is finitely generated, we can assume that $N \subseteq Ax$. Thus we can identify both $N$ and $M \cap Ax$ with ideals of $A$. Because of Lemma 1, we can assume moreover that $M = A$. Given $a \in N \setminus \{0 \}$, we have $N \cap Aa = Aa \subseteq aN$. Therefore $N = A$.

Comment: This is essentially equivalent to my proof, but with the induction done in a much nicer way (its equivalent came in the GCD domain step, where I used it pairwise to get the same result).

Comment: I don't understand how to justify the last line. Also, it is easy to construct counterexamples without the UFD assumption. For instance in $k[t^2,t^3]$,  the submodule of the free module $(x,y)$ satisfying $t^2 x - t^3 y=0$ is obviously closed under division, but isn't free as it is isomorphic to $k[t]$, which isn't free over $k[t^2,t^3]$.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks for your remark. You are absolutely right, I really got carried away! I rolled back to my previous answer, which is, I believe, correct.

Answer (score 2):

Free modules $M$ over a GCD domain have the following property: If $x \in M$, $a^{-1} x \in M$, and $b^{-1} x \in M$, and $a$ and $b$ have no common factors, then $(ab)^{-1} x \in M$. Indeed, it suffices to check this for the free module of rank one, where the claim is that if $x$ is divisible by $a$ and $b$ where $a$ and $b$ share no common factors then $x$ is divisible by $ab$ - obvious from unique factorisation.

If $N \subseteq M$, $M$ has this property, and $N$ is closed under division inside $M$, then $N$ shares this property.

Any rank one, finitely generated, module over a Noetherian ring with this property is free: Let $x$ generate a maximal free submodule, $y$ another element, then because it is rank one, $y = (a/b)x$ for some $a,b$ with no common factors, hence $ax=by$ is divisible by $a$ and $b$, hence $x$ is divisible by $b$. Since $x/b$ cannot generate a larger free submodule, $b$ is a unit, and hence $y$ is a multiple of $x$.

Comment: In general, a finitely generate module is a submodule of a free module closed under division if and only if it is reflexive. (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AV2)  For UFD's, a module satisfies the $a^{-1},b^{-1}$ divisibility criterion if and only if it is reflexive, and rank one reflexive modules over UFDs are free. But verifying these facts seems more complicated than just proving it directly.

Comment: You may replace UFD by GCD on every turn.

Comment: @LucGuyot Good point, although I think I need a Noetherian hypothesis in the last step to ensure there is a maximal free submodule - unless there is some way to remove it?

Comment: I see a way to remove the Noetherian assumption if you impose a seemingly stronger condition, namely: If $x \in M$ and $a^{-1}x \in M, b^{-1}x \in M$, then $\text{lcm}(a,b)^{-1}x \in M$. Now take any non-zero $x$ in $N$ and use the fact that $N$ is finitely generated by $y_1, \dots, y_n$ and of rank $1$. We can write $y_i = \frac{a_i}{b_i}x$ with $a_i^{-1}x \in N$ so that $\frac{1}{\text{lcm}_i(a_i)}x$ generates $N$.

Comment: @LucGuyot Good point! That condition is not actually stronger, as you can just apply my stated condition to $gcd(a,b)^{-1}x$. So only GCD is needed for the final result.